# simulink discrete integrator block problem

Tags: discrete-signals, lowpass-filter

I am testing the Simulink discrete integrator block as shown in the picture below. The simulation is fixed step with $T_s = 1e-5$ and the cosine wave block setting and the scope display is also shown below.

[image]
[image]
[image]

For the discrete integrator block, the gain value K is set to be 1 and the integration method was chosen to be "Accumulation: Forward Euler". However, how come the magnitude of the result is so big as shown in the top part of the scope picture? I thought integrating a cosine wave will produce a sine wave with the same magnitude. If the integration method is chosen to be "integrator: Forward Euler", the result becomes very small, as shown below. It just can't produce a sine wave with magnitude of 1. How to get the correct result?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

All of a sudden I realized I made a silly mistake.
$$
\int \cos(\omega\cdot t)dt=\frac{1}{\omega}\sin(\omega\cdot t)
$$
which means the "integrator: Forward Euler" choice produced the correct result.